# How large of a planet could we build a space elevator on?

Tags: material-science, estimation, space, solar-system-exploration

Currently, we don't know of any material that has a high enough tensile strength to weight ratio to construct a space elevator on Earth. But this has me wondering, with the materials we do have, what's the biggest planet or moon we theoretically could build a space elevator on? What's the current upper limit (assuming a body with roughly the density of Earth)? And could we build one on Mars, our moon, or other large moons in the solar system?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lunar_space_elevator says we could do one on the Moon with current materials.